# Extract Aflresco documents from command line

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I would like to know if it is possible to access the documents that Alfresco keeps. I want to make a project to generate a zip for each user registered automatically.

Thanks

Comment: You need to elaborate on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Nothing, I already got it, after 5 days of work, I got a query that obtained the location of a document depending on the customer number from which I wanted to obtain the elements. Generate the zip and send by email.

Thank you and I'm sorry